# Not able to rotate view in youtubeplayerview android

Tags: android, youtube, rotation

I have an activity with youtubeplayerview. Why I click on the full screen button on the view, the video does not rotate.Instead the blank screen is shown.

My code is as follows:

```
youtube = (YouTubePlayerView)findViewById(R.id.youtube_view1);
    youtube.initialize("APP_ID",this);
public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, final YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {

    if (!b) {

        if(deeplink == false) {
            youTubePlayer.loadVideo(youtube_ID);

        }
        else
        {
            youTubePlayer.loadVideo(youtube_ID_deeplink);
        }
    }

}

@Override
public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {

}
```

I am not able to understand where I am going wrong. Please suggest.

Comment: Can you give the whole Activity code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In manifest file inside the activity tag add

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

like this

```
<activity 
android:label="ActivityName" 
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
android:name="com.example.app.ActivityName" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code snippet

```
youTubePlayerSupportFragment.initialize(API_KEY, new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
                                youTubePlayer.addFullscreenControlFlag(YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_ALWAYS_FULLSCREEN_IN_LANDSCAPE);                                    
                                youTubePlayer.loadVideo(Uri.parse(mVideosList.get(position).getLink()));
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
                                                                YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {
                                System.out.println("onInitializationFailure");
                            }
                        });
```